# C++ in powershell

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

I am in an environment which has no C++ compiler software installed, and I was wondering if it was possible for me to compile C++ code without having to install anything.

Comment: Please define *"execute C++ in powershell"*

Comment: Do you want to compile a c++ program and run the executable in powershell?  Or are you expecting powershell to understand C++ syntax by itself?

Comment: @woolstar powershell to understand C++ syntax by itself

Comment: You do it the same way you execute Visual Basic in LISP. Or colloquial modern Turkish in FORTRAN 77. PowerShell is a language, and C++ is a different language.

Comment: Would C# be enough or you need strictly C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within PS run `help add-type -full` and look for the F# example (example 7 on my system). Assuming you have a C++ compiler that follows the "CodeDom" model, you can mirror the F# example.

Of the two alternatives you gave, I'm going to go with "blindly obvious"